# Best way to calculate $T_0$ of a laser diode material

Tags: temperature, semiconductor-physics, laser, electronics

In the following [website](https://www.laserdiodecontrol.com/laser-diode-parameter-overview) it is described that to calculate the T0 of a laser diode, I have to take a laser of specified geometry, find the threshold currents at different temperatures and plot their logarithms against temperatures:

[image]

[image]

But isn't it inconvenient, that we obtain data that are specific to one laser length only? Wouldn't it be better to use Transparency Threshold Current Density (which is length-independent material characteristic) instead? This way we would characterize the material itself.

Isn't my way of thinking flawed? Maybe TTCD shouldn't be used, and T0 should be calculated on per-length basis?

Answer (score 0):

This paper

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228807884_Temperature_Dependence_of_Blue_InGaN_Lasers

shows a simple calculation of T0 based on the threshold current vs. temperature. It's not required to know threshold current density using the formula as described in section 3. Hope this helps!